# Shopware SEO URL with product options names in it

Tags: shopware, shopware5

I want to have my product urls like this:

`bla.com/product_name_bla_white_140cm`

white & 140cm are options I can select at the given product.

I thought I can set it via SEO URL template:

`{{ product.translated.name}}{%for opt in product.options %}_{{opt.name}}{%endfor%}`

but with this setting, the url is like: `bla.com/detail/261927b50317410ba8eecc97d77c3b7e`

what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `\Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Seo\SeoUrlRoute\ProductPageSeoUrlRoute::prepareCriteria` the association for options and options.group are not loaded, so you won't be able to access this data. The easiest way would be to add these criteria by plugin.